# SQL (Impala) query syntax error for timestamp range

Tags: python, sql, impala

I am using the following query to find the data given the timestamp constraint:

```
query = 'select my_id, my_ts from my_table limit 100 where my_ts >  "2016-05-13 00:00:00"'
cursor = impala_con.cursor()
cursor.execute('USE my_database')
cursor.execute(query)
```

But get the following error:

```
HiveServer2Error: AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 1:
...my_ts from my_table limit 100 where my_ts >  "201...
                             ^
Encountered: WHERE
Expected: AND, BETWEEN, DIV, ILIKE, IN, IREGEXP, IS, LIKE, LIMIT, NOT, OFFSET, OR, ORDER, REGEXP, RLIKE, UNION

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
```

---

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_limit.html#limit) you need to specify `limit 100` *after* the where clause.

```
query = 'select my_id, my_ts from my_table where my_ts >  "2016-05-13 00:00:00" limit 100'
```